# openlayer vectorSource error with json data

Tags: javascript, json, openstreetmap

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
   projection: 'EPSG:4326'
}); 

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
   source: vectorSource
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'mapdiv',
    renderer: 'canvas',
    layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()}),vectorLayer],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform([2.1833, 41.3833], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 2
    })
});

var sessionData = {"4798":{"location":[{"lat":27.714622020721,"lng":85.31263589859}]},"5873":{"location":[{"lat":59.944732189178,"lng":17.821261882782}]}};

createMarkers(sessionData);//this function has issues

//this function has no issue
function addFeatures() {
    var i, lat, lon, geom, feature, features = [];
    for(i=0; i< 10; i++) {
         lat = Math.random() * 174 - 87;
         lon = Math.random() * 360 - 180;

         geom = new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lon,lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
         feature = new ol.Feature(geom);
         features.push(feature);                    
    }   
    vectorSource.addFeatures(features);                
}

//this function show error
function createMarkers(sessData) {
    var geom, feature, features = [];

    $.each(sessData,function(key,val) {         
        var locations = val.location;
        if(location.length == 0) {
            return true;
        }

        $.each(locations,function(index,value) {
            if(value.lng == 0 || value.lat == 0) {
                return;
            }
            geom = new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([value.lng,value.lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));                   
            feature = new ol.Feature(geom);
            features.push(feature);
        });
    });
    vectorSource.addFeature(features);
}
```

addFeatures and createMarkers function has very similar codes. addFeatures function has no issues but when createMarkers function is called, it shows an error "Uncaught TypeError: a.addEventListener is not a function" at line "vectorSource.addFeature(features)"

Comment: fixed. its a silly typo error of (s). wrote vectorSource.addFeature(features) instead of vectorSource.addFeatures(features)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed by adding (s) at the end of addFeature. its addFeatures instead of addFeature.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you...

```
    var coords = [];
    for (var i=0;i<7;i++){ 
        var x= Math.random()*360-180; 
        var y= Math.random()*180-90;
        coords[i]= [x,y]; 
    } //end for

    var mapCenterCoord = [-65.65, 10.10];       

    var lineString = new ol.geom.LineString(coords);
    lineString.transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'); 

    var feature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: lineString,
        name: 'Line'
    });

    var lineStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#0080FF',
            width: 3
        })
    });

    var source = new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [feature]
    });
    var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: source,
        style: [lineStyle]
    });

    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.OSM() }), vector],
        view: new ol.View({ center: mapCenterCoord, zoom: 3 })
    });
```

Regards.

J.